# Structural D flip flop in Verilog

Tags: fpga, verilog

```
module dFlipFlop(
    input clk,
    input d,
    output q
    );
wire w1,w2,q_n;

assign w1 = ~(d & clk);
assign w2 = ~(~d & clk);

assign q = ~(w1 & q_n);
assign q_n = ~(w2 & q);

endmodule
```

will this module work as a D flip flop on my fpga? Any suggestions? I dont currently have my FPGA, but im trying to figure out if this design is worthy or not.

Comment: FYI: You write a D latch, not a edge triggered flip flop

Comment: Before asking questions like this, you should learn the definition of a flip-flop and then think of how you can implement it, what you write here is not a flip-flop, it is a latch as Greg mentioned.

Answer (score 3):

It might work, but it's hard to say what the synthesizer will do with that.  It is a much better idea to use an always block when you want to do use a clock.

Answer (score 0):

No, not as a flip-flop.  It is a D latch.

The difference occurs when clock is high.  A flip-flop will register the input, d, at the clock edge.  The d latch will allow the registered value to change when clock is high.

A D-Latch Truth Table would look like:

```
Clk  D  |  Q(t+1)
-----------------
 0   x  |   Q(t)
 1   0  |    0
 1   1  |    1
```

x = don't care (doesn't matter what it is).

A d flip-flop would change only on the edge (or some time after depending upon the delay).

Worthy design? -- As you may know, this is not the simplest and usually would not be a recommended method of creating either a d latch or a d flip-flop.